# Using le vs les in sentence

Tags: gramática

Which one is correct?

> 1. A mis padres le pusieron la vacuna.
> 2. A mis padres les pusieron la vacuna.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be interesting to know which one you think is correct and why.

Comment: Nice that you are interested! “Les” makes sense. It’s just that “Le” somehow sounds ok. If I change the order, sounds even better: “Le pusieron la vacuna a mis padres”. Perhaps it is just a misuse in my dialect? I don’t know :/

Comment: However, I would say, for example: “El médico les puso la vacuna”. But if I add “a mis padres”, then I would say: “El médico le puso la vacuna a mis padres”. Is there a complicated grammar I’m missing here? Probably :/

Comment: The verb form is"  poner la vacuna a **los padres**, plural. The les goes with padres plural not with vacuna.

Comment: It makes total sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singular "le" may sound fine to you because it is an extended practice, though not strictly correct.

According to [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos), though wrong the use of singular "le" before a plural indirect object is widespread even among educated speakers:

> 6. Discordancias en el uso de los clíticos. [...]:
>
> a) A menudo, cuando el pronombre átono de dativo concurre en la oración con el complemento indirecto preposicional, se utiliza el singular *le*, aunque el referente sea plural; esta discordancia está extendida tanto en España como en América, incluso entre hablantes cultos, por lo que son frecuentes, aunque normativamente desaconsejables, oraciones como «Colombia le propuso a los Gobiernos de Estados Unidos y Venezuela una alianza» (Tiempo [Col.] 18.4.97). En el uso esmerado se recomienda mantener la concordancia de número entre el pronombre átono y el sustantivo al que se refiere: «Los mismos remedios de distracción que les daba a sus enfermos» (GaMárquez Amor [Col. 1985]).

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is correct: "les" refers to ‘mis padres’ (plural).

Answer (score 0):

Le pusieron refers to parents as a singular object. Les pusieron is referring as them both (plural).
Both are used but the plural is more common.
Colombia Spanish